# Is there any free system for testing fs security implementation?

Tags: filesystems, software-rec, fuse, access-control, testing

I'm writing my own Fuse filesystem and I'm in need of good testing, in particular the access control implementation investigation, as I've already found test suites for I/O. There will be other things like locking, but I'm not there yet. (But you can cover this in your answer, most welcome.)

Is there any free and open software for this? Or at least something close, even good documentation, as the border between this user fs and the kernel and Fuse library side is often blurry and I'm not sure if what I do is superfluous or outright wrong. Gracias.

Comment: What sort of testing? Access control testing isn't hard. There are only 3 accessors (owner, group, world), 3 bits of permission (`rwx`) per accessor, and 2 results (succeed or fail), plus ACLs.

Comment: @waltinator There are also the special bits, file types, error codes, access modes, what else? All these multiply into quite a number of tests.